# How to create rpm A which support overlapping of installed rpm B files?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to create rpm A, my requirement here is that whenever I install rpm A, It will replace some files which are part of installed rpm B.

for this in debian we used

```
Provides: pkg C
Conflicts: pkg C
Replaces: pkg C
```

Replacing whole packages, forcing their removal.

How can I do this in rpm spec file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 solutions.

1. Overlapping is not in supported rpm spec, but we can use commandline option `rpm A --replacefile`.
2. Use `Obsoletes:` in RPM A spec file to remove older package or conflict packages and add `Provides:` in RPM A to make RPM B happy.

   Note: for option 2
   rpm -i RPM A --> will not obsoletes packages. we have to use
   yum install RPM A or rpm -U RPM A

Answer (score 0):

If you want RPM B to go away, then yes, the same thing "`Provides`" (to make other RPMs looking for B happy) and "`Conflicts`" (to force the uninstall of B).

If you want B to stick around, then you're out of luck unless you can do a few esoteric things. The easiest would be to do something like `myorg-common` which contains these files and then `myorg-a` and `myorg-b` which conflict with each other but both require `myorg-common` (and provide each other).

Comment: I did the same but getting error like "file xyz from install of RPM A conflicts with file from package RPM B"

Comment: Yes, you can't install them at the same time.

Comment: As per you answer RPM B should force uninstall ?

Comment: Yes, A should refuse to install.